# Ubercart Discounts (Alternative) needs Content module

Tags: ubercart

I have installed Ubercart in Drupal 7. My client needs to be able to have special pricing for members, so I added Ubercart Discounts (Alternative). I also installed CCK as a per-requisite. However, the installed module says it needs the Content module. I am not able to find this module.

Answer (score 0):

Content is the core module of CCK. You can find it under the CCK section of your module install page.

[image]

Comment: It wasn't there. So, I've deleted CCK and I'm trying to reinstall it.

Comment: Make sure to uninstall the modules before replacing the code files.

Comment: It doesn't want to go away. It shows as disabled in the module list, but it doesn't show in the uninstall list.

Comment: No worries then, if it doesn't show up in the uninstall list the data schema is now gone. You should be ok to try a clean install of CCK's Content and other needed modules.

Comment: Assessing the current situation, it does not seem to match your answer precisely.
1. I have cleared the cache in Configuration more than once
2. The CCK group still appears in the Module list (not enabled)
3. CCK does not appear in the Uninstall list
4. The files are still on the server
Why would a module that is not enabled not show up on the Uninstall list?

Comment: From what it sounds like, the data schema was never installed. If it's not showing up in the uninstall list, you should be safe to enabled/install now.

Comment: Should I only be seeing one table for CCK: cck_field_settings? Should that table have any records after enabling?

Comment: I reinstalled both CCK and uc_discounts_alt module with the same problems. I don't think that Content is supposed to show at all in Drupal 7, but the Discounts module Codeless Discounts Field submodule doesn't seem to recognize that. I may have to start over with Drupal Commerce.

Comment: If this is a new project that doesn't need UC for legacy/requirement reasons, I highly recommend using Commerce in favor of UC. I'll leave that as the last word; comments aren't discussion threads on DA and this discussion is offtopic from your original question.